# How to Reinitialize Table controller list using Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, salesforce

I have used 2 table one with oututField and another with InputFields in my code and using jquery datatable i am constructing a table.

Button Clicks: Edit -- Opens Datatable in Edit Mode (Input Field) 
Cancel -- Opens datatable in ReadOnly Mode(OutputField)

Desc: When i click Edit Button, Table is opened in EDIt MODE, if  i change some values of input field and click cancel, rendered table in RO mode.

Problem: If again i click Edit button the changes i have made in last step persist.

I want: Table list should be refreshed from DB and should show original list.

Script Tag:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="DtscriptId">
    <script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    var EditCheck = "{!EditCancelDispCheck}";
    var extdisplayPopup ="{!extdisplayPopup}";
    console.log('EditCheck'+extdisplayPopup);
    var table;
   if(EditCheck == 'false' || extdisplayPopup == 'false'){
        console.log('Inside Data Table Script1');
        document.getElementById("divextdataEditTableId").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("divextdataTableId").style.display = "block";
        table = $('#extdataTableId').DataTable();
    }

     if(EditCheck == 'true'){
        document.getElementById("divextdataTableId").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("divextdataEditTableId").style.display = "block";
        $("#extdataEditTableId").fadeTo(0,1.00);
       $('#extdataEditTableId').DataTable().destroy();

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
        {
            return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
                return $('select', td).val();
            } );
        }
        /* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column, parsed as numbers */
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text-numeric'] = function  ( settings, col )
        {
            return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
                return $('input', td).val().replace(/\s/g,'') * 1;
            } );
        }
        /* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column */
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text'] = function  ( settings, col )
        {
            return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
                return $('input', td).val().replace( /,/g, "." ).replace(/\s/g,'') * 1;
            } );
        }
        /* Initialise the table with the required column ordering data types */
            $('#extdataEditTableId').DataTable( {
                "bDestroy" : true,
                "columns": [
                    null,
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    null,
                    null,
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text"},
                    null
                ]
            } ); 
     }

    if(extdisplayPopup == 'true'){
        $("#extdataEditTableId").fadeTo(0,0.4);
    }  

    function renderFirstTable(){
        document.getElementById("divextdataEditTableId").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("divextdataTableId").style.display = "block";
        var dataTable = $('#extdataTableId').DataTable();
        dataTable.clear();

        <apex:repeat value="{!existingRowList}" var="i">
          dataTable.row.add([
            '{!i.Product__r.Name}',
            '{!i.OS__c}',
            '{!opportunitymarket}',
            '{!opportunitycountry}',
            '{!i.Quarter__c}',
            '{!i.Year__c}',
            '{!i.Quantity__c}',
            '{!i.Total__c}',
            '{!opportunitycurrency}'
            ]).draw();
        </apex:repeat>

     }

     </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I want: Is there any possibility to refresh Edit Table with DB list using jquery and render the script panel only, because if I render the table panel it looses it's jquery Datatable property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Rendering won't solve the problem as inputfield binds the value and to refresh it there are two ways

1. Refresh the list in jquery(as no matter you refersh in controller or use any other list it won't leave the value)
2. copy the data of output field to input field on cancel.

   ```
   function ResetValues(){
       var opptid ="{!opptid}";
       result = sforce.connection.query("select id, Country__c,Price_Per_Unit__c, Product__r.Name, Quantity__c, OS__c, Quarter__c, Total__c, Year__c from Shipped_Units__c where opportunity__c = '"+opptid+"'");
       records = result.getArray("records");
       for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
           console.log('records1'+records[i].Quantity__c);
           var inpos = i +'-inpOS';
           var inpqtr = i +'-inpQtr';
           var inpyear = i +'-inpYear';
           var inpunit = i +'-inpUnit';
           var inptotal = i +'-inpTotal';
           var osid=document.getElementById(inpos).childNodes[0];
           var qtrid=document.getElementById(inpqtr).childNodes[0];
           var yearid=document.getElementById(inpyear).childNodes[0];
           var unitid=document.getElementById(inpunit).childNodes[0];
           var totalid=document.getElementById(inptotal).childNodes[0];

           document.getElementById(osid.id).value=records[i].OS__c;
           document.getElementById(qtrid.id).value=records[i].Quarter__c;
           document.getElementById(yearid.id).value=records[i].Year__c;

           document.getElementById(unitid.id).value=parseInt(records[i].Quantity__c);
           document.getElementById(totalid.id).value=parseInt(records[i].Total__c);
       }

   }
   ```

or Similar to below line of code

```
j$(InpIdmodsp).val(document.getElementById(outsp.id).innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JQuery to do what you are trying to do.

I would suggest you create a class Property in your Extension or Custom Controller class to keep the state of the edit mode:

```
public with sharing class ExampleExtensionClass {

    public Boolean editMode {
        get {
            if (editMode == null) {
                editMode = false;
            }
            return editMode;
        }
        set;
    }

}
```

Then in your VF page you can bind a Apex Action Function to a Checkbox onchange event to rerender the table in edit mode:

```
<apex:page standardController="SObject" extensions="ExampleExtensionClass">

    <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderTable" reRender="tablePanel"/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!editMode}" onChange="rerenderTable();"/>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="tabelPanel">
        <apex:dataTable value="{!sObjectList}" var="sObjectrecord">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputField value="{!sObjectrecord.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(editMode)}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!sObjectrecord.Name}" rendered="{!editMode}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```